# Count number of li element and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to count `li` elements, and `addClass` to another div.

For example:

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function(){
  return 'list' + $(this).find('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>


<div class="box2">text</div>
```

This should be like this

```
<div class="box2 list3">text</div>
```

But I don't know why when I check on the DOM code,

```
<div class="box2 list0">text</div>
```

I get this result.

What do I need to fix the code? 
Please help.

Comment: Your `$(this)` is not pointing to `.box2` as you expect

Comment: @Mr.Alien It is what it actually does, pointing to `.box2`, hence not working as expected as there is no `.box1` _after_ it.

Comment: It would be great to add `$(document).ready(function(){`, around your JQuery operations,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your query looks for `.box1 li` *within* `.box2`, though these two elements are siblings. Therefore, your `find()` query  will always return `0`.

For your query to work, your `HTML` would need to look like this:

```html
<div class="box2">text
  <ul class="box1">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Without altering the structure of your `HTML`, you can get this to work by accessing `.box1 li` directly:

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function(){
  return 'list' + $('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>

<div class="box2">text</div>
```

Comment: This explanation is wrong, even if `box2` was before `box1`, `$(this)` evaluates to div `box2` and looks for `.box1 li` among `box2`'s descendants

Comment: @barbsan Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the example with a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 8):

Here `$(this)` is referring to `box2` element.Only `$('.box1 li').length` is what you required

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function() {
  return 'list_' + $('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```css
.list_3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

[*this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is not pointing to the element you are thinking, it is referring to *DIV* element on which the [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is invoked and this element does not have `.box1 li`. Thus [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) is failing to refer your intended element.

Simply use:

```
$('.box1 li').length
```

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function(){
  console.log(this.nodeName); // DIV
  return 'list' + $('.box1 li').length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`$(this).find` will find the `li` in the `div` with `box2` class which are not present. Instead check this in the `div` with `box1` class and find the `li` elements

```js
$('.box2').addClass(function(){
  return 'list' + $('.box1').find('li').length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>


<div class="box2">text</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this by following method

```js
$('.box2').addClass('list' + $('.box1 li').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="box1">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div class="box2">text</div>
```